# make castle widsor not load all modules

Tags: castle-windsor

I am using castle windsor to dynamically load some modules. is it possible to ask castle widsor to not load a specific module? I want to instantiate that module manually and then add it to the list of modules

Comment: @Kozmic say I have 10 classes that instantiate Ifoo but I want to load all but one of them. I want to use something like ResolveAll().Except() I cant find something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment (I think you meant components, not modules?) you can use `IHandlersFilter` in Windsor 3. See [this blogpost](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/2264) for details.